# Make Atlas zoom over all the selected element at once in QGIS 3.6.2

Tags: qgis, atlas, composer-manager

With the "is_selected" function and a virtual field created with the field calculator, it is possible to make Atlas zoom over the selected elements, one each time.
Is it possible to make Atlas zoom over all the selected elements at once?

Comment: Can you please explain further what you mean with " zoom over all the selected elements at once"? Thanks :)

Comment: I want Atlas to manage the set of selected elements as if it were just one element, only in terms of framing and zooming.